# autoload class map with composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

directory:

```
myproject:
   src:
      MyProject:
           Foo:
              Foo.php
```

in file autoload_namespaces.php

```
return array(
    'MyProject' => array($vendorDir . '/myproject/src'),
);
```

if declare look like this:

```
class Bar extends MyProjext\Foo\Foo
{

}
```

or:

```
use MyProjext\Foo\Foo;

class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

it working, but i want declare not using 'use MyProjext\Foo\Foo;' or 'extends MyProjext\Foo\Foo'

```
class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

this is error: 'class Foo not found', somebody can help me?

Comment: And what is namespace of `Bar` class?

Comment: class Bar not have namespace, look like in laravel, class BaseController extends Controller, class BaseController not have namespace, class Controller namespace is Illuminate\Routing\Controller

Comment: Show class declaration starting from `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> it working, but i want declare not using 'use MyProjext\Foo\Foo;' or
>   'extends MyProjext\Foo\Foo'

Which means this works:

```
use MyProject\Foo\Foo;

class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

But this doesn't work (you want to make it working):

```
class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

It's not working because the class `Bar` is trying to extend the class `Foo` from global scope but the class `Foo` is declared under `MyProject\Foo` [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and it's stored in `MyProject/Foo` directory, so the error is happening and it's logical.

If you want to use this code (without any `namespace`):

```
class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

Then make sure that, the class `Foo` is in available in the global namespace and find a line like `namespace MyProject\Foo;` before your `Foo` class declaration and remove that line and also include the class `Foo` before you use it (by extending) to create class `Bar`. So, it could look like this:

```
// You may need to adjust the path
require_once("MyProject/Foo/Foo.php");

class Bar extends Foo
{

}
```

Use of `namespace` is better so try to stick with it, without `namespace` your current `autoloading` technique may fail unless you rewrite it without use of `namespace`.